# Use config file in App\Libraries Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, config

i have one non-laravel library at the App\Libraries and there i have file providers.php

```
    <?php

return [

    'slsp'=> [
        'SLSP_SPOROPAY_PU_PREDCISLO'=> '000000',
        'SLSP_SPOROPAY_PU_CISLO'=> '0013662162',
        'SLSP_SPOROPAY_PU_KBANKY'=> '0900',
        'SLSP_SPOROPAY_SHAREDSECRET'=> 'Z3qY08EpvLlAAoMZdnyUdQ==',
        'SLSP_SPOROPAY_REDIRECTURLBASE'=> 'http://epaymentsimulator.monogram.sk/SLSP_SporoPay.aspx',
    ],

    'paypal'=>[

        'PAYPAL_USERNAME'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_PASSWORD'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_SIGNATURE'=>'xxxx',
        'PAYPAL_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT'=>'3333',
        'PAYPAL_RETRY'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_OGENABLED'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_FILENAME'=>'foo/bar',
        'PAYPAL_LOGLEVEL'=>'5',

    ]

];
```

and than i would like get and set this value like

```
Config::get('providers.paypal.username');
Config::set('providers.paypal.username', 'someName');
```

What i must do when i want using it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach would be to create a laravel provider and register the provider in app providers.

For Example:

In your case

`php artisan make:provider EPaymentProvider`

It will create a provider file `EPaymentProvider.php` in `providers` directory.

Now modify your `Library/EPayment.php` file like this

```
<?php

class EPayment {

    private static $_instance = 'null';
    public $credentials = [
        'PAYPAL_USERNAME'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_PASSWORD'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_SIGNATURE'=>'xxxx',
        'PAYPAL_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT'=>'3333',
        'PAYPAL_RETRY'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_OGENABLED'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_FILENAME'=>'foo/bar',
        'PAYPAL_LOGLEVEL'=>'5',
    ];

    /**
     * @param array $array
     */
    public function setPayPalCredential(array $array){
        $this->credentials = $array;
    }

    /**
     * @return EPayment|string
     */
    public static function PayPal(){
        if(self::$_instance === 'null')
            self::$_instance = new self;

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPayPalCredential($key){
        return $this->credentials[$key];
    }
}
```

and in `register` method of `EPaymentProvider.php` add `Libraries/EPayment.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        require base_path().'/app/Libraries/EPayment.php';
    }
}
```

Now add `EPaymentProvider` in `config/app.php` Provider array

Now you can use
    `Epayment::PayPal()->setPayPalCredential(['PAYPAL_USERNAME' => 'New Username']);`
and
    `Epayment::PayPal()->getPayPalCredential('PAYPAL_USERNAME')`

let me know if it worked.

Comment: hi when follow your steps i get this error: "App\Providers\EPaymentProvider::register(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/pay/app/Libraries/TomajPayGateways/EPayment.php.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')"

Comment: could be permission issue.  and could be some typo because `/var/www/html/pay/app/Libraries/TomajPayGateways/EPayment.php.php` containg two `.php` extension. do let me know if anything works out.

Comment: yes ther was .php two times, but now i have `Class 'App\Providers\EPaymentProvider' not found` but EpaymentProvider is in /Providers.

Comment: try `php artisan optimize` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` finished correct but `php artisan optimize` get me : `Class 'App\Providers\EPaymentProvider' not found in /var/www/html/pay/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'App\Providers\EPaymentProvider' not found         
                                                     `

Comment: check namespace of EPaymentProvider. it should be `namespace App\Providers`

Comment: yes yes ther is `namespace App\Providers ` any idea?

Comment: i've to see your code, teamviewr or anywhere else. can I see?

Comment: och my bad i had wrond name of class EPaymentProvider :D Now it working corectly. Thank you

Comment: have you added `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class` in `config/app.php` providers array correctly ?

Comment: Glad to help you @JánAmbroz :)

Answer (score -1):

First the file is outside the config folder so it wont be possible to set or get using the Config facade. To still use the providers file move it to the config directory and everything will work for you.

Comment: And what if i need file have in app/libraries?

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve `config` values using dot notation, you can do the following in `providers.php`:

```
$paypalArray = ['paypal' =>
    [
        'PAYPAL_USERNAME'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_PASSWORD'=>'xxx',
        'PAYPAL_SIGNATURE'=>'xxxx',
        'PAYPAL_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT'=>'3333',
        'PAYPAL_RETRY'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_OGENABLED'=>'true',
        'PAYPAL_FILENAME'=>'foo/bar',
        'PAYPAL_LOGLEVEL'=>'5']
    ];

config($paypalArray);
```

Now you can retrieve values like `config('paypal.PAYPAL_USERNAME')`.